# "Star Trek" novel with Kirk and Picard encountering a giant Borg drone

Tags: star-trek, novel, episode-identification

I'm looking for the title of a *Star Trek* novel in which the heroes encounter a Borg drone who was about three meters tall.

I think the heroes were Kirk and Picard (which implies this is a Shatnerverse story), and the scene may have taken place at a Federation starbase that had been assimilated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Likely [*Star Trek: The Return*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Return_(Shatner_novel)) (1996), part of the [Shatnerverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Trek_novels#Shatner_concept_series) series of books.

> A blinding blue flash came from the side opposite Weinlein’s approach. Picard faltered, momentarily startled by what he saw. The Borg response was overwhelming. A configuration **unlike any Borg** Picard had ever encountered.
>
> It was bipedal, but **three meters tall**, with piston-like legs and thick crushing disks for footpads, digging into the soil. Propellant gases hissed from its leg joints as it began to stalk forward. Two pairs of arms swung forward, searchingly, manipulators opening and closing with molecularly sharp carbon cutters and whirling blades. Their target: raw materials.

[image: book cover, two half-faces with the tagline "Legends never die"]

Comment: Thanks! Posting your answer on TVTropes under "Giant Mook"